# How to combine 2 scripts with different conditions

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 scripts with different condition.

Script 1:

```
select l2_respond_by,count(l2_respond_by) as total
from master_apps_issue
where l2_respond_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
group by l2_respond_by;
```

Script 2:

```
select l2_return_by,count(l2_return_by) as total
from master_apps_issue
where l2_return_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
group by l2_return_by;
```

Now I need 1 query that generates COUNT results in both and want a result like this.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If `LATERAL` joins were supported (they are in MySQL 8+):

```
SELECT
  rrr.name
, SUM(rrr.action = 'respond' ) AS total_l2_respond_by
, SUM(rrr.action = 'return'  ) AS total_l2_return_by
, SUM(rrr.action = 'resolved') AS total_l2_resolved_by
FROM
  master_apps_issue AS mai
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT
      mai.l2_respond_by, 'respond'
    WHERE
      mai.l2_respond_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-09 23:59:00'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      mai.l2_return_by, 'return'
    WHERE
      mai.l2_return_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-09 23:59:00'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      mai.l2_resolved_by, 'resolved'
    WHERE
      mai.l2_resolved_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
  ) AS rrr (name, action)
GROUP BY
  rrr.name
;
```

The `rrr` subquery unpivots your set conditionally, returning only the people and events that match a corresponding time constraint.  The main `SELECT` effectively pivots the rows back, aggregating them in the process.

A live db<>fiddle demo is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d8a43d73a94131a53a8eb5a4b639f2e).

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be some assumptions in this answer. As there is no sample dataset with which to test the results, keep these in mind and be sure to adjust the query to suit your situation:

1. the `COUNT()` functions are using an `id` of some sort rather than a `user_id`, as this makes it much easier to verify accuracy
2. the source table is assumed to contain a large number of `NULL` and duplicate columns, hence the "similar but different" names
3. there is no transaction table for `master_apps_issue`, making a single query without the derived table all but impossible (This can likely result to historical data changing if the `l2_respond_date` field is ever updated).

With those notes aside, here is a query that may provide what is being requested:

```
SELECT tmp.user_id,
       SUM(tmp.responses) as total_l2_respond_by,
       SUM(tmp.returns) as total_l2_return_by,
       SUM(tmp.solutions) as total_l2_resolve_by
  FROM (SELECT l2_respond_by as user_id, COUNT(ticket_id) as responses, 0 as returns, 0 as solutions
          FROM master_apps_issue 
         WHERE l2_respond_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
         GROUP BY l2_respond_by
         UNION ALL
        SELECT l2_return_by as user_id, 0 as responses, COUNT(ticket_id) as returns, 0 as solutions
          FROM master_apps_issue 
         WHERE l2_return_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
         GROUP BY l2_return_by
        UNION ALL
        SELECT l2_resolved_by as user_id, 0 as responses, 0 as returns, COUNT(ticket_id) as solutions
          FROM master_apps_issue 
         WHERE l2_resolved_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
         GROUP BY l2_resolved_by) tmp
 GROUP BY tmp.user_id;
```

Comment: Hi @matigo, how if I add 1 query from your query. For sample, I want to add:

select l2_resolved_by,count(l2_resolved_by) as total
from master_apps_issue
where l2_resolved_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
group by l2_resolved_by

Comment: The subquery has been updated. Please note that this query is quickly becoming very "ugly". If this is the sort of thing that you'll be doing often, it may be worthwhile to look into having a proper transaction table for this sort of thing. It will drastically simplify queries and allow you to have immutable historical records.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really possible to do this in one scan: the grouping and filtering are completely different.

**It seems a `full join` would be more in order here:**

```
select
  ifnull(resp.l2_respond_by, ret.l2_return_by) as userid,
  resp.total as total_respondby,
  ret.total as total_returnby
from (
    select l2_respond_by, count(l2_respond_by) as total
    from master_apps_issue
    where l2_respond_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
    group by l2_respond_by
) as resp
full join (
    select l2_return_by, count(l2_return_by) as total
    from master_apps_issue
    where l2_return_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-09 23:59:00'
    group by l2_return_by
) as ret on ret.l2_return_by = resp.l2_respond_by;
```

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, thank you and it is worked with left join. Can share the same query if I want to add 1 query below:

select l2_resolved_by,count(l2_resolved_by) as total from master_apps_issue where l2_resolved_date BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' and '2021-07-09 23:59:00' group by l2_resolved_by

Comment: @enggal - if you have a new question, please hit the [ask](/questions/ask) button.  Please take a look at [mcve] for details about how to write a clear question.